# Custom partials of TYPO3 form

Tags: forms, typo3

How can I set custom partials for the TYPO3 form extension?
Is it possible to set this in the template under "Setup"? For example

```
plugin.form {
    view {
            partialRootPaths >
            partialRootPaths {
                    0 = fileadmin/form_partials
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439950/typo3-form-multicheckbox-partial

Answer (score 0):

Your typoscript is possible, but it is more malicious than helpful.

There is a build-in fall back mechanism for templates (or this time: partials) you will destroy.

If you want to replace FLUID templates (layouts, templates, partials) with your own version of a file you can add their folder to the array of paths with a higher number. The highest index is considered first on the search of a FLUID file and then there will be a fall back to the next lower number, until no further folder is available.

If you remove all entries and set your own you need to have **all** FLUID files in your folder - even if you have not modified anything compared to the original.
Especially if you modify the output of an extension with a system of FLUID files you need to copy a lot of files. and you might miss some important enhancements on the next update in files you only copy.